# Reading rwd files in python

Tags: python

I want to read data from a .rwd file into Python. The file contains data on wind energy from NRG systems. IS there a way I can write parsers for new file types in Python. Being a beginner I am not sure whether I am using the correct terms in the question, so please bear.

The data I am reading contains wind energy data from NRG systems. They have a converter which converts .rwd files to .txt but works only on Windows. They haven't given any more information about whether the .rwd is encoded or not.I basically want to read it through Python because I want the software to work on Windows.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should [edit] it to add more relevant details that are specific to your issue, e.g, the format of the file, what information you want to extract from it and what code you've already tried to read the file with.

Comment: First you would have to get the specs on that format. Once you have that, you can write a parser - unless they are encrypted.

Comment: Where can I get the specs from? The organization that provides this file has propriety issues.